# Jquery tablesorter filters & ajax pager

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, tablesorter

I'm using [this](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) tablesorter library to sort & filter data in a table. I'm also using [this](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html) plugin to be able to split the table into multiple pages.

Since the number of records in my table was getting rather large, loading of the page was getting to slow (>60 seconds), So I wanted to change the behavior of the page, by loading the contents of the table with a ajax call.

To do that, I used the example on this page: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html

and created a separate page that executes a query and returns json. So far so good, pagination works and filtering en sorting also works.

The one issue that I'm facing is that some of the columns have a "dropdown" filter (by adding class="filter-select" to the column). This dropdown was automatically populated by the tablesorter plugin with values in the column.

Now that I made the switch to loading the data with a ajax call, these filters are not populated anymore when the page is initially loaded. When I enter some data in one of the other fields, the dropdowns are all of a sudden populated.

To get to the base of the problem, I've stripped down my code into a simple sample, in which I still can reproduce the issue. The code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/tablesorter.css?v=239319">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.combined.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.css">
<script src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>

<TABLE id='issueTable' class="tablesorter search-table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <TR>
        <TH><B>Issue number</B></TH>
        <TH><B>Registered by</B></TH>
        <TH><B>Province</B></TH>
        <TH class="filter-select"><B>Departement</B></TH>
    </TR>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="rowlink">
    </tbody>
</TABLE>

<div id="pager1" class="pager">
    <form>
        <img src="/js/tablesorter_pager_images/first.png" class="first"/>
        <img src="/js/tablesorter_pager_images/prev.png" class="prev"/>
        <span class="pagedisplay" data-pager-output-filtered="{startRow:input} &ndash; {endRow} / {filteredRows} van {totalRows} meldingen"></span>
        <img src="/js/tablesorter_pager_images/next.png" class="next"/>
        <img src="/js/tablesorter_pager_images/last.png" class="last"/>
    </form>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var table = $("#issueTable");

        var pager1Options = {

            container: $("#pager1"),
            page: 0,
            size: 20,
            pageReset: 0,
            ajaxUrl: 'meldingen.json',

            ajaxProcessing: function (data) {

                if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('rows')) {
                    var indx, r, row, c, d = data.rows,
                        // total number of rows (required)
                        total = data.total_rows,
                        // array of header names (optional)
                        headers = data.headers,
                        // cross-reference to match JSON key within data (no spaces)
                        headerXref = headers.join(',').split(','),
                        // all rows: array of arrays; each internal array has the table cell data for that row
                        rows = [],
                        // len should match pager set size (c.size)
                        len = d.length;
                    // this will depend on how the json is set up - see City0.json
                    // rows
                    for (r = 0; r < len; r++) {
                        row = []; // new row array
                        // cells
                        for (c in d[r]) {
                            if (typeof(c) === "string") {
                                // match the key with the header to get the proper column index
                                indx = $.inArray(c, headerXref);
                                // add each table cell data to row array
                                if (indx >= 0) {
                                    row[indx] = d[r][c];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        rows.push(row); // add new row array to rows array
                    }
                    // in version 2.10, you can optionally return $(rows) a set of table rows within a jQuery object
                    return [total, rows, headers];
                }
            },
        };

        table.tablesorter({
            widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],

        }).bind('pagerChange pagerComplete pagerInitialized pageMoved', function (e, c) {
            var msg = '"</span> event triggered, ' + (e.type === 'pagerChange' ? 'going to' : 'now on') +
                ' page <span class="typ">' + (c.page + 1) + '/' + c.totalPages + '</span>';
            $('#display')
                .append('<li><span class="str">"' + e.type + msg + '</li>')
                .find('li:first').remove();
        }).tablesorterPager(pager1Options);

    });
</script>
```

For this sample I used a simple json file, like this:

```
{
  "total_rows": 5,
  "headers": [
    "Issue number",
    "Registered by",
    "Province",
    "Departement"
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "Issue number": "914288",
      "Registered by": "Jan",
      "Province": "Utrecht",
      "Departement": "Department 1"
    },
    {
      "Issue number": "914289",
      "Registered by": "Piet",
      "Province": "Utrecht",
      "Departement": "Department 1"
    },
    {
      "Issue number": "914290",
      "Registered by": "Klaas",
      "Province": "Utrecht",
      "Departement": "Department 1"
    },
    {
      "Issue number": "914288",
      "Registered by": "Erik",
      "Province": "Utrecht",
      "Departement": "Department 2"
    },
    {
      "Issue number": "914288",
      "Registered by": "Bart",
      "Province": "Utrecht",
      "Departement": "Department 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

With this plain JSON file, the filtering will of course not work, but you can see that the filter for the column "Departement" is initially not populated, it does get populated as soon as you type something in any of the other columns.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

**Update 2017-08-04:**

I am now population the filters with a ajax request. For that I've added this to the widgetOptions :

```
filter_selectSource: {
4: function (table, column, onlyAvail) {

                        $.getJSON('tablesorter_resources/filters.php?column=Department', function (data) {
                            var result = data.hasOwnProperty('options') ? data.options : false;
                            $.tablesorter.filter.buildSelect(table, column, result, true, onlyAvail);
                        });
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    }
```

However according to the documentation, I should do it this way:

```
filter_selectSource: {
4: function (table, column, onlyAvail) {
                        console.log(table.hasInitialized);

                        // call ajax after tablesorter has initialized; this prevents
                        // multiple ajax calls during initialization
                        if (table.hasInitialized) {

                        $.getJSON('tablesorter_resources/filters.php?column=Department', function (data) {
                            var result = data.hasOwnProperty('options') ? data.options : false;
                            $.tablesorter.filter.buildSelect(table, column, result, true, onlyAvail);
                        });
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    }
```

But I see that table.hasInitialized returns false, so when I add that condition, the filter does not get populated.

I also noticed that the page size is set to 30 since I switched to population via ajax, even though I'm only really getting 20 records per page from the database and I set size: 20. Any idea why that would be ignored?

Comment: The `table.hasInitialized` flag is set after all widgets have initialized, so the above function may not get executed until the user uses the filter. Also, if the list doesn't get dynamically updated by the user, it would be better to get the list of filters outside of the `filter_selectSource`, on page initialization, then pass an array to this setting.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the filter select populates the dropdown with the contents of the table. To add selections not available, use the [`filter_selectSource` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource) to either populate a fixed number of values or get the data directly from your database via an ajax call. See the examples in the documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mottie, that does actually make sense, Since I'm only retrieving the first 20 record from a set of 900, the tablesorter can not even properly populate the filter if it wanted to :).I've added some extra info to my question above.